# Sharepoint servers down?

Tags: sharepoint-server

Every now and then me and my users loose access the site and no SharePoint related pages load. We get a wrong message and that's it.

I can not find a solution to this, have anyone else had the same problem?

Comment: What server version and patch status do you have?

Comment: what error you are getting, please share the log(uls and Event) as well as browser error details....Your question is very much generic.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I am using Sharepoint 2013 and browser doesnt matter, it does not work in any browser. It basically tell me that an unexpected error has occured and thats it.

Comment: i am asking what error display in the browser? is it one line unexpected error? what error in the ULS logs / Even log. For me looks like a Database connectivity issue.

Comment: That was my initial thought as well.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a complete installation, check the Database server connection, you can do a `ping <DB server IP> -t` in the command prompt of the SP server and check if the network drops.